# Combination of document.addEventListener and document.execCommand("copy") does not work in Safari

Tags: safari, addeventlistener, execcommand

I have the following code, which works completely fine in Chrome/Edge/Firefox,
newest versions of course, but I expect even a few year old browsers of these will work just fine.

Now in Safari 15.3 (newest I think, at least very recent) this code does not work at all.

```
function copy() {
 const copyListener = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", "Random text data");
    event.clipboardData.setData("text/html", "<div>Random html data</div>");
 };
 var eventListenerOptions = {
    capture: true,
    once: true,
 };
 document.addEventListener("copy", copyListener, eventListenerOptions);
 document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

Let's imagine that this `copy()` function is called inside of a `onClick` handler.

Then after the `onClick` is triggered, then the `document` did register this `eventListener`, but it is just not triggered instantly by the `document.execCommand("copy")` call. It is only triggered when I after the `copy()` call select something manually on the screen and do ctrl+c.

So question time:
(1) I have heard somewhere that Safari does not emit a real copy event without any user interaction, which I guess I have confirmed sort of, it is user interaction to click on the button that calls `copy()` in its handler right? But maybe not the correct type of interaction. Is there any good official documentation on this? I tried to look at https://developer.apple.com/safari/ but it doesn't really provide you anything useful I think.

(2) I have seen code snippets around, and all of them for Safari uses range selections in the dom, and then call `document.execCommand` so an eventual solution for me is to use this as well, do a check to see which browser and then fallback to the range selection, I just do not think it supports any granularity in regards to "plain/text" and "plain/html" so I really want to avoid it because of that + less complexity if I could tweak this a little to make it work on all 4 browsers.

Any answers/comments are greatly appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Safari does not support this idiom supported by Firefox/Edge/Chrome/etc.

There is a bug report that have not been active since 2019
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=156529